# Using Sync Framework in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-2012-localdb

Does anyone have a walkthrough or video on how to use Sync Framework in VS 2013? I've seen nice examples using VS 2010 but some important items like local database cache object have been deprecated.

For what I have read is that LocalDB will be replacing the Sql Compact (which is deprecated). But have not found a site explaining how things should work. My solution for what I understand would be a LocalDB syncing with a SQL Server with IIS using WCF. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no equivalent for the Local Database Cache project wizard in VS 2013. if you want to do what the wizard does, you can hand code it yourself. but that will be using the older sync providers.

you can find a walkthrough of how to achieve this with the newer sync providers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700(v=sql.110).aspx). The SqlSyncProvider should work with SQL Server/Express/LocalDB/Azure. You can also still SQL CE if you want to.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the link I ended up using. Thanks